# Any way to condense these regular expressions into one?

Tags: php, regex

I have a couple of directories containing around 10,000 files each. I want to read through the files and write the data to specific columns in a database. The problem I'm having is with speed. I'm using `preg_replace_callback` with multiple regular expressions stored in an array.

I need help figuring out how to condense the regular expressions into a single expression, if at all possible, or finding a better way of achieving the same goal without regular expressions.

Each data file looks like this, only larger:

```
Company: Google, Since: 1998
Longitude: 37.422, Latitude: 122.084
Email: google@gmail.com
...
```

I'll use the following code to demonstrate the performance:

```
class DataParser
{
    public $data;
    public $regexes;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->regexes = array(
            'company_since' => '/Company: ([a-z_]+), Since: ([0-9]+)/i',
            'longit_latit' => '/Longitude: ([0-9.]+), Latitude: ([0-9.]+)/',
            'email' => '/Email: ([a-z0-9_\-.]+)@([a-z0-9_\-.]+)/i'
        );
    }

    function parse($data)
    {
        static $key = 0;

        foreach ($this->regexes as $name => $regex) {
            preg_replace_callback($regex, function($str) use($name, $key)
            {
                $this->data[$key][$name] = array($str[1], $str[2]);
            }, $data);
        }

        $key++;
    }
}

// This is normally in a file
$data = 'Company: Google, Since: 1998' . PHP_EOL
      . 'Longitude: 37.422, Latitude: 122.084' . PHP_EOL
      . 'Email: google@gmail.com';

$exec_start = microtime(true);
$parser = new DataParser();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $parser->parse($data);
}

echo round(microtime(true) - $exec_start, 5), '/s';

echo '<pre>', print_r($parser->data, true), '</pre>';
```

The output is:

```
0.13795/s

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company_since] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Google
                    [1] => 1998
                )

            [longit_latit] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 37.422
                    [1] => 122.084
                )

            [email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => google
                    [1] => gmail.com
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company_since] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Google
                    [1] => 1998
                )
...
```

The script is getting slower with each added regular expression, but it performs well with only one regular expression. Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question or trying to fix the wrong problem, in which case: What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` most likely has replacement overhead (the result of which is not used). If each data file contains one record, you might want to invoke `preg_match`, since it will only search for the first match.

Comment: For combining the regex formulas, why not just use `$this->regexes = array('/Company: ([a-z_]+), Since: ([0-9]+).*Longitude: ([0-9.]+), Latitude: ([0-9.]+).*Email: ([a-z0-9_\-.]+)@([a-z0-9_\-.]+)/mi');`? This can probably be written better, but since the order seems to be the same for each record, it should work.

Comment: Paul: The order isn't always the same, and some information isn't always present.

Comment: With a more large sample of datas, it will be more easy to help you to find a better method. Possible that the use of regex is not the best approach.